# Android Whether the file exists File.isFile() / flie.exists() Advantages and disadvantages Which one is recommended

Tags: java, android

Which scheme is recommended for judging the existence of files

1.

```
 if(new File(path).isFile()){
            Log.i(TAG, "path: YES");
        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "path: NO");
        }
```

2. 

```
 if(new File(path).exists()){
            Log.i(TAG, "path: YES");
        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "path: NO");
        }
```

Comment: you are comparing apple to orange, the two methods are totally different things

Answer (score 0):

`isFile()` and `exists()` both have different purpose or usage.

**1. isFile()**
It will return true if the file is a normal file, not a directory/folder (returns false for folder or directory(.

**2. exists()**
It will return true if the path (file or folder) exists, otherwise return false.